# How can I configure EclEmma Eclipse plugin to read Jacoco's agent tcpserver dump

Tags: eclipse, jacoco, test-coverage, eclemma

I´m using EclEmma plugin to make coverage tests. And I´d like to include information of EJBs deployed in an AppServer (specifically weblogic 10.3.6) to the final coverage report. 
I found Jacoco project has an agent that writes that information to a TCP socket with the output=tcpserver parameter.

Is it possible to configure the EclEmma plugin to connect to this tcpserver and read this information on the fly?

I'm trying to avoid manually importing the session dump after the server has been shutdown. I'd like to launch my test suite and see the full report afterwards without any extra steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to EclEmma documentation you can connect to JaCoCo agent using [Coverage Session import wizard](http://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/importexport.html) that can be activated form the `File -> Import...` menu. And then

> use the Refresh option from the context menu of the Coverage view or simply hit the F5 key

to re-import the data as often as you want.